# About C# WinForms Data Binding (Using INotifyPropertyChanged) and Data Refreshing Issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, data-binding

I'm a beginner, and I'm developing a network program using C# WinForms. The program continuously attempts to read data from a remote server and synchronously displays it in my TextBox. Additionally, when a user modifies the TextBox through input and presses Enter, a message to modify the corresponding data on the remote server should be sent. This is my requirement.

I have implemented data binding using INotifyPropertyChanged and BindingList. However, this data binding is preventing me from modifying the content of the TextBox on the user interface. When I try to modify this value and send a modification message, entering data different from the original, if new data is received from the continuously reading remote server, it gets synchronized and refreshes the TextBox. This results in the inability to input content for modification on the interface.

This is my ValueBinding class

```
    public class ValueBinding : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int _value;
        public int Value
        {
            set
            {
                if (value != _value)
                {
                    _value = value;
                    // change
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
                }
            }
            get { return _value; }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoke
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

and I use this code to create my BindingList:

```
BindingList<ValueBinding> valueList = new BindingList<ValueBinding>();
ValueBinding valueBinding = new ValueBinding();
valueList.Add(valueBinding);
// Binding TextBox
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", valueList[0], "Value", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

The code below is to send Change to Server when user Press ENTER Key:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        SendChangemessage(textbox.Text);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Someone Please Help me solve this puzzle.

I tried adding a boolean flag in the BindingValue class to distinguish changes caused by the reception of messages within the program from changes due to user input, but for some reason, it was not successful. The problem still persists; when I input data different from the current value, it gets refreshed due to updates from the backend data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to temporarily remove data binding to prevent the data from updating when modified.

```
// Init DataBinding
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", valueList[0], "Value", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

---

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
}

private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", valueList[0], "Value", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

Additionally, I try creating a new custom control with an update-allowed property, inheriting from textBox, and checking if updates are allowed at the trigger point.

```
 public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
 {
     private bool allowTextBoxEdit = true;

     public bool AllowTextBoxEdit
     {
         get { return allowTextBoxEdit; }
         set { allowTextBoxEdit = value; }
     }

     protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
     {
        // Allow or Not 
        if (allowTextBoxEdit)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
        }
     }
  }
```

---

```
 private void CustomTextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // User Edit
     CustomTextBox customTextBox = sender as CustomTextBox;
     customTextBox.AllowTextBoxEdit = false;
 }

 private void CustomTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // User Edit over
     CustomTextBox customTextBox = sender as CustomTextBox;
     customTextBox.AllowTextBoxEdit = true;
 }
```

Similarly, modify this property in the Enter and Leave events.

Answer (score 0):

That is how two-way bindings work, the control is bound to a single source and has no concept of knowing *why* the value changed or what changed it.

There are a number of solutions to this, but it gets complicated if you are using bindings alone because at one point you need to suppress updates from one source while the other is being modified.

The complication is both *how* to identify that an edit is happening and how to notify that you have *ended* the edit.

One solution to this is to change your `ValueBinding` so the external value change can be differentiated from the UI change and we can expose the state:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Binding that defaults to a background value that changes rapidly
/// But allows for the User to edit itserver value 
public class ValueBinding : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int? _displayValue;
    public int DisplayValue
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != _displayValue)
            {
                bool wasModified = IsModified;
                _displayValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                if (!wasModified)
                   OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsModified)); 
            }
        }
        get 
        { 
            return _displayValue.GetValueOrDefault(_serverValue); 
        }
    }

    /// <summary> Helper to identify if the DisplayValue has changed </summary>
    public bool IsModified { get => _displayValue.HasValue; }

    public int _serverValue;
    /// <summary>
    /// Bind this to the external caller
    /// It will only update the DisplayValue
    /// if the DisplayValue has not been set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// When the next server value received matches the DisplayValue, 
    /// we will reset the Display value.
    /// </remarks>
    public int ServerValue
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != _serverValue)
            {
                int previousValue = value;
                _serverValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                // Check if we need to reset the user edit
                // AKA - the server has received the change
                if (_displayValue.HasValue 
                    && _displayValue.Value.Equals(value))
                {
                    _displayValue = null;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsModified));
                }
                if (!_displayValue.HasValue)
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayValue));
            }
        }
        get => _serverValue;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoke
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

However even this simple solution will have issues for some specific value entry scenarios because the change detection still doesn't know that the user is actively editing, but typing slowly.

- This is not a typical binding scenario, it might be better while you are learning to separate these two concepts into 2 different fields in the UI, perhaps make the server control readonly.

This type of binding scenario is much better managed at the control level, you create a custom control that can bind to 2 properties that will have similar logic to this, but then because you are inside the control context you have access to other properties like is the control has focus or mouse hover giving you greater control over the behaviour, it will also make it easy to color the background or set a tooltip which will help the user to identify between a server value and a local one.